# unity-control-center printers does not bring up the printer panel

Tags: unity-control-center

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

when I type unity-control-center sound, the sound panel comes up
when I type unity-control-center power, the power panel comes up
But
when I type unity-control-center printers, the entire panel of all services comes up, i.e., it's exactly as if I'd just typed unity-control-center.

Is there a way of fixing this?

thaks

Comment: Not sure why it is not coming up.  It doesn't for me either.  But you can run `system-config-printer` to bring it up by itself.

Comment: That's great!   Thanks very much, do you want to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `unity-control-center` command line if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> after typing it in it will show you all the options you can bring up.

```
:~$ unity-control-center 
appearance        info              power             universal-access
bluetooth         keyboard          printers          user-accounts
color             mouse             region            --verbose
datetime          network           screen            --version
display           --overview        sound             wacom
```

However, for some reason the `printers` part is not working.  I don't know if it is a bug or not.  But, the printers part can be launched from a command line with the following command:

```
system-config-printer
```

[image]

Hope this helps!